# two divs on top of each other while third after them

Tags: html, css

I have this layout:

```
  <div id="content">
    <div id="foreground">
    </div>
    <div id="background">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
```

I need background div displayed under foreground div, this I have done using position:absolute and it works ok.

problem is after setting both foreground and background absolute position they are taken out of normal flow, parent div (content) has no real width and this screws up footer position.

```
#background
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:-1;
}
#foreground
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1;
}
#content
{
    position:relative;
}
#footer
{
    position:relative;
}
```

Content width is dynamic so I can't set absolute position to footer and I really would like to avoid some javascript hacks, is there any solution to this?

Comment: Do you have an image on how you would want it to look?
What content will there be?

Comment: Can't you just put the foreground div inside of the background div? That would give it what I think you're after.

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but the title sounds like the name of a bad porno !

Comment: thanks for ideas, @Rupo posted exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done it like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="foreground">
        Row 1<br>
        Row 2<br>
        Row 3<br>
        Row 4
    </div>
    <div id="background">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footer">
    The footer
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#background
{
    float: left;
    background-color: #ff0;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#foreground
{
    float: left;
    z-index:1;
}
#content
{
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#footer
{
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4LSZK/

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't set a height on `#content`? So, something like this:

```
#content {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}

#foreground {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 2;
}

#background {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
}

#footer {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DuWRe/1/

(I've added some borders and backgrounds so each element's position can be easily identified.)

Comment: Yeah, but there is a problem, that the background and the foreground should cover all of unknown width of the parent #content

Comment: Updated answer with slight changes and a new fiddle.

Comment: sorry, this won't work as #foreground position changes, it is not the same all the time.

Comment: It's position is absolute so you can place it anywhere without interrupting the flow of the page. Maybe you could add some specifics as to what these elements are and what you want to do with them.